# A HashMap which its values are collections - should this data structure be named?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-structures

From time to time I run across the need to use a **HashMap which its values are collections**. In C# it'd be a `IDictionary<TKey,IEnumerable<TValue>>`.

I also have a nice "Add" Extension Method for it:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensionMethods
{
    public static void ExtendWith<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>> dict, TKey key, TValue item)
    {
        IEnumerable<TValue> items;
        dict[key] = (items = dict.ValueOrDefault(key)) != null ? items.Union(new[] { item }) : new[] { item };
    }
}
```

Should this Data Structure be named? Design Patterns are all about defining and and naming programmers' folklore, or, things we usually do repeatedly...

How about naming this guy? Is it a good idea at all? If so, what name would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [MultiDictionary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/06/19/would-you-like-a-multidictionary.aspx) - don't re-invent the wheel.